# Android OpenGL texture from non-local source using Rajawali3D?

Tags: android, opengl-es, rajawali

I am using the OpenGL library Rajawali3D to display my models. What I would like to know is how can I load a texture from my server based on the logged in user? I've searched all over the internet trying to figure this out for months with no success. I found this website that explains how to load a texture from a non-local source but when I tried it, it didn't work with Rajawali. Any suggestions or examples would be much appreciated.

Here's the website I attempted to use: [texture from web](http://www.softwaysolutions.com/blog/opengl-texture-non-local-source-android/)

Comment: You should be able to download a texture as any app would download an image.I would first start with trying to download the texture/image to local storage before transforming it into a bitmap. There are examples of loading textures from Bitmap in https://github.com/Rajawali/RajawaliExamples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Rajawali, however as I just checked it out, it seems fairly easy to load a remote texture and apply it to a model.

I presume that you've loaded your 3D model and can show it fine. If so, you should take the following basic steps (which apply generally to all 3D modeling apps):

1. Prepare texture
2. Prepare material
3. Apply material to a model

There's a class called `Texture` in Rajawali, which creates a texture object from a bitmap image. So, you should first download that image from your server. Downloading process is apart from Rajawali concepts, so you can get it done via many existing libraries.

Once you're finished downloading the image, you can feed it to the `Texture` class.

```
Texture mytexture = new Texture("texture", /*address to the downloaded image*/);
```

Then, you should add it to a material

```
try {
    material.addTexture(mytexture);

} catch (ATexture.TextureException error){
    Log.d(TAG, "Error Occurred");
}
```

Now, you can apply this material to a model

```
model.setMaterial(material);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been trying to figure this out for months. You're a life saver!!